# i am getting an error while deploying my node application backend on render

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Error:

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1147
  throw err;

  ^
Error: Cannot find module './connectionState'
```

[render uses node version--20.10.0 --> error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JE8Qp.png)

one more thing, when I built the app using the `npm run build` command and then ran the app using npm start(production level), the MongoDB didn't connect (i have already added the IP addresses). But when I start the app using npm run dev (in development mode), the Mongodb connects without any problem.

I have already reinstalled the node modules, replaced `bcrypt` with `bcryptjs`, and installed `mongoskin` also.

I am using Node version v18.17.
NPM version-10.2.5

[list of packages from server file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0meAV.png)

Comment: It would help if you provided a [mcve] extracted from your setup. Also, avoid images of text, use the text directly so it can be (hint!!) searched for. As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].